# Ideals in $\left\{\frac{m}{2^n}\mid m\in \mathbb Z, n\in \mathbb N_0\right\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Consider the subring $R=\left\{\frac{m}{2^n}\mid m\in \mathbb Z, n\in \mathbb N_0\right\}$ of $\mathbb Q$. Show that for any ideal $I$ of $R$ there is an ideal $J$ of $\mathbb Z$ with $I=\left\{\frac{m}{2^n}\mid m\in J, n\in \mathbb N_0\right\}$.

Any hints or suggestions at least to get started?

Comment: This is the ideal correspondence theorem for localizations (this is $\Bbb Z$ localized away from $2$)

Comment: @KennyLau It resembles Prop. 6.7 from http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf, but not quite

Comment: This is exactly Prop. 6.7(b).

Comment: @KennyLau For me this is not obvious at all why this is 6.7(b). It says that if you take an ideal in the localization, take its inverse image under the localization map, and then consider the ideal generated by the image under the same map, you get the ideal back. Why is it the same as what is required in the present problem?

Comment: Note that $\{\frac{m}{2^n}| m\in J, n\in \mathbb N_0\} = J^e$. 6.7(b) claims that $I = (I^c)^e$, which gives $J$ as $I^c$ as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of $J$ is simply $J = I \cap \Bbb Z$. It is routine to check that this is an ideal.

We claim that $I=\left\{ \frac{m}{2^n} ~\middle|~ m\in (I \cap \Bbb Z), n\in \mathbb N_0 \right\}$.

For $\subseteq$, note that if $\frac m{2^n} \in I$, then $m \in I$, so $m \in (I \cap \Bbb Z)$, so $\frac m{2^n} \in \left\{ \frac{m}{2^n} ~\middle|~ m\in (I \cap \Bbb Z), n\in \mathbb N_0 \right\}$. $\supseteq$ is clear.

---

More generally, referring to [Stacks 10.9.16](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02C9), if $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of a ring $R$, then we can form the ring $S^{-1}R$, and again every ideal in $S^{-1}R$ can be expressed in the form $S^{-1}I$ where $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

In this case, $R = \Bbb Z$ and $S = \{ 2^n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$.

Comment: So here $I\cap \mathbb Z$ is $I^c$? How could one come up with setting $J=I\cap \mathbb Z$ if one didn't know about that fact on contractions/extensions?

Comment: is that asking "how can I come up with this answer if I have never learnt it?" if so, I don't know the answer to that.